# C# JSON Returns a List Inside List

Tags: c#, json, list

```
public class Entry
{
    public string playerOrTeamId { get; set; }
    public string playerOrTeamName { get; set; }
    public string division { get; set; }
    public int leaguePoints { get; set; }
    public int wins { get; set; }
    public int losses { get; set; }
    public bool isHotStreak { get; set; }
    public bool isVeteran { get; set; }
    public bool isFreshBlood { get; set; }
    public bool isInactive { get; set; }
}

public class SummonerId
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string tier { get; set; }
    public string queue { get; set; }
    public List<Entry> entries { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<SummonerId> Summoner_Id { get; set; }
}
```

I have genereated this class using **Json2csharp.com**.

Where the class has 1 List I am able to access the data with no problems.

But with this class generated 2 Lists. I think I am over thinking now and have become very confused..

How can I deserialize this class

```
string url = json.ToString();

var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(url):
```

`Summoner_Id` returns as `null`.

```
var id = root.Summoner_Id;
```

root returns as `null` also..

How can I solve this? Please help or point me in the right direction!

Comment: show your JSON, is it starts and ends with brackets [ and ]?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.

     {"Summoner_Id":[{"name":"Fiora's      Inquisitors","tier":"GOLD","queue":"RANKED_SOLO_5x5","entries":[{"playerOrTeamId":"585709","playerOrTeamName":"AP Ezreal Mid","division":"IV","leaguePoints":61,"wins":175,"losses":158,"isHotStreak":false,"isVeteran":false,"isFreshBlood":false,"isInactive":false}]}]}

Comment: This is the correctly formatted version of your JSON....
[  
   {  
      "name":"Fiora's Inquisitors",
      "tier":"GOLD",
      "queue":"RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
      "entries":[  
         {  
            "playerOrTeamId‌​":"585709",
            "playerOrTeamName":"AP Ezreal Mid",
            "division":"IV",
            "leaguePoints":61,
            "wins":175,
            "losses":158,
            "isHotStreak":fal‌​se,
            "isVeteran":false,
            "isFreshBlood":false,
            "isInactive":false
         }
      ]
   }
]

Comment: try this `var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Summoner_Id>(url)` and rename your `SummonerId` class to `Summoner_Id`

Comment: All the values are still returning as null.
entries null,
name null,
queue null,
tier null

Comment: i edit my prev. comment

Comment: Thanks Pravin for your reply, I am getting the JSON format directly from the api. I havent changed it.. is there any way I might have changed it? or is there a way I can reformat it so I can use? Thanks.

Comment: @cerberus - Still returning as null values.
Ive changed the class name to Summoner_Id , no luck :(

Comment: and changed this also? `<Summoner_Id>`

Comment: I just used this https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to see if it is valid or correctly formatted.

Comment: Yeah, ive set a breakpoint just after  var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Summoner_Id>(url);

to see what root changes.
but the values are still null.

Comment: @user6256751 Please add your JSON to the question

Comment: @user6256751 can you give api url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example works for me:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Test {
    static class Program {
        static void Main() {

            string json = @" {
    ""Summoner_Id"": [{
        ""name"": ""Fiora's Inquisitors"",
        ""tier"": ""GOLD"",
        ""queue"": ""RANKED_SOLO_5x5"",
        ""entries"": [{
            ""playerOrTeamId‌​"": ""585709"",
            ""playerOrTeamName"": ""AP Ezreal Mid"",
            ""division"": ""IV"",
            ""leaguePoints"": 61,
            ""wins"": 175,
            ""losses"": 158,
            ""isHotStreak"": false,
            ""isVeteran"": false,
            ""isFreshBlood"": false,
            ""isInactive"": false
        }]
    }]
 }";

            var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
            Console.WriteLine(root.Summoner_Id);
        }
    }

    public class Entry {
        public string playerOrTeamId { get; set; }
        public string playerOrTeamName { get; set; }
        public string division { get; set; }
        public int leaguePoints { get; set; }
        public int wins { get; set; }
        public int losses { get; set; }
        public bool isHotStreak { get; set; }
        public bool isVeteran { get; set; }
        public bool isFreshBlood { get; set; }
        public bool isInactive { get; set; }
    }

    public class SummonerId {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string tier { get; set; }
        public string queue { get; set; }
        public List<Entry> entries { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject {
        public List<SummonerId> Summoner_Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```